# AutoMapper Project().To<T> and reusable lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, automapper, iqueryable

I am having a problem getting a reuasable lambda expression working with the AutoMapper Project().To extension method. I am using AutoMapper 3.1.1.

I want to be able to reuse a lambda expression by defining it as a variable, but am having issues getting this to work with the extension method.

Note the code and lambda expression shown below are simplified, my lambda expression is very complicated and I want to reuse it in a number of places.

Here is a lambda expression to reuse:

```
Func<Product, bool> myLambda = x => (x.Season.Id == 3);
```

**Code Block 1** uses Project().To<> and the reusable lambda, and wont even compile.

```
var dtos =
                _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.All()
                    .Where(myLambda)
                    .Project().To<ProductGridDTO>()
                    .OrderBy(dynamicSort)
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(take)
                    .ToList();
```

It gives the following compile error:

**Error 18**

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Project' and no extension method 'Project' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Code Block 2** uses .Select() and Mapper.Map() and compiles and works, but the SQL query generated returns all columns. I want to use Project().To<> to only return a minimal set of  columns in the SQL query, and thus be more efficient and quicker.

```
var dtos =
                _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.All()
                    .Where(myLambda)
                    .Select(y => Mapper.Map(y, new ProductGridDTO()))
                    .OrderBy(dynamicSort)
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(take)
                    .ToList();
```

**Code Block 3** uses Project().To<> and the same lambda but as inline code. It compiles and works okay, but does not let me reuse my lambda expression.

```
        var dtos3 =
            _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.All()
                .Where(x => (x.Season.Id == 3))
                .Project().To<ProductGridDTO>()
                .OrderBy(dynamicSort)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(take)
                .ToList();
```

Is there any way I can get **Code Block 1** working. Is there another way I can defined my lambda expression to get around this compile error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IQueryable` objects do not work with delegates, they work with [Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You initialize them the same way but you must declare it differently.

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> myLambda = x => (x.Season.Id == 3);
```

Try that out and see if it work.

The problem is because you passed in a delegate you ended up using [this version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `.Where(` which outputs a IEnumerable, The problem is `.Project<T>()` requires a `IQueyable<T>` and to get that you must use [this version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `.Where(` which you can see only take in a `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` not a `Func<TSource, bool>`.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I had previously tried this before, but I think I had other issues at the time with my code which was causing other errors. I tried it again at your prompting and it now works beautifully. Thankyou!